# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  92 | <Router>
  93 |   <ul>
> 94 | {this.state.movielist.map(a => <li onClick={() => this.handleClick(a.title)}>{a.title}{a.description} <button type="button" onClick={() => this.singledelete(a.title)}>delete</button> </li>)}
  95 |     </ul>
  96 |     </Router>enter code here




  68 | handleClick = (title) => {
> 69 |     this.state.movielist.push("/edit")    
  70 | }
```

can any one help why i am getting this error

Comment: at a guess, `this.state.movielist` is **not an array** - but without seeing your code, it's a guess

Comment: try updating state with this.setState();

Answer (score 0):

You should use setState inside your click handler to update your movelist state variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `movieslist` as a blank array in the constructor first.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      movieslist: []
    };
  }
```

You click handler goes like this -

```
handleClick = (title) => {
   this.setState({ movieslist : [...this.state.movieslist,'/edit'] });
}
```